# How to split a sentence into words based on the special Characters

Tags: java

I want to split a sentence into words based on the special character(like "=")
I tried the following code, But couldn't get the exact answer, See my Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class RunExe {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            Process pr=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("VmgDiskActivityTest.exe");
            BufferedReader rd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String lines=rd.readLine();
            String[] words=null;
            while(lines!=null)
            {
                System.out.println(lines);
                //System.out.println("*******************");
                words=lines.split("=");
                lines=rd.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println("After Spliting");
            //System.out.println("***************************");
            for(String word:words)
            {
                System.out.println(word);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

the output of the code is:

0 C: D: E:=99.993340#0.000000#0.035810#0.000000#0.000179#0.000358#0.000000#0.000000#0.000000#1.999614#3071.407671
_Total=99.993340#0.000000#0.035810#0.000000#0.000179#0.000358#0.000000#0.000000#0.000000#1.999614#3071.407671

After Spliting
_Total
99.993340#0.000000#0.035810#0.000000#0.000179#0.000358#0.000000#0.000000#0.000000#1.999614#3071.407671

The above code split-ed correctly but I couldn't get exact result.
It displayed only last two part of the strings, I need to display the all four parts.

Please share your Ideas or Solutions...

Answer (score 2):

You read the line in the loop, split it, and assign to `words` array, defined outside. 
On the next iteration, you get the next line, split it, and (re-) assign the same array. 
After the the last iteration, the `words` array therefore contains the results of splitting the last line, that's what you print out in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You override the contents of the array `words` every time you enter the loop. As such only the last split line will represent it's contents.

You can add a `Map` of arrays for each line and store the results in that.

```
String lines=rd.readLine();
String[] words=null;
Map<Integer,String[]> map=new HashMap<Integer,String[]>();
Integer index=0;

while(lines!=null)
{
  System.out.println(lines);
  //System.out.println("*******************");
  words=lines.split("=");
  map.put(index,words);
  index++;
  lines=rd.readLine();
}
```

Then simply iterate through the list and get the split array for each line (index represents the line number starting from 0)

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String[]> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Line " + entry.getKey());
    for(final String content: entry.getValue()){
        System.out.println(content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the line `words=lines.split("=");` you basically overwrite your words-Array and therefore will always only get the results from the last `lines` string.
To achieve what you want, you should use an `ArrayList<String>` instead of the `String[]` and then you could write `words.addAll(lines.split("=");`.
In the end, you will have an ArrayList with **all** entries instead of only the last two.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizer class for this

you have to import StringTokenizer `import java.util.StringTokenizer;`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            Process pr=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("VmgDiskActivityTest.exe");
            BufferedReader rd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String lines=rd.readLine();
            String[] words=null;
            StringTokenizer st2=null;
            while(lines!=null)
            {
                System.out.println(lines);
                //System.out.println("*******************");
                //words=lines.split("=");
                st2 = new StringTokenizer(lines, "=");

                lines=rd.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println("After Spliting");
            //System.out.println("***************************");
              while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
                   System.out.println(st2.nextElement());
              }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```